# Was javax's NotNull removed in Java 8?

Tags: java, netbeans, annotations, java-8

Looking at the documentation for `NotNull` under Java 7, you can see `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` is a [valid and documented annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html). However upon navigating to the same page for Java 8, I receive a 404.

Netbeans suggests to import `com.avaje.ebean.validation.NotNull`, which is **not** what I want (it doesn't support nearly as many placements).

I've heard of the tag `NonNull` instead, but I can't find java documentation nor can I import it in netbeans. What am I meant to be using in Java 8?

Comment: Does Netbeans provide the Java EE libraries? You don't just `import` types and expect them to be available. You have to put the libraries, ex. a `.jar` file, on the classpath at compile and runtime as needed.

Comment: I suppose it would have to, since my maven doesn't have a java EE dependency added in. Perhaps I should look into whether or not it automatically supplies those jars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`javax.validation` is not part of Java 8, it is part of Java EE, and is still included in [Java EE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/)

Comment: But I have support for that, as I'm able to import `javax.validation.Nullable` just fine.

Comment: Adding on, seems strange that I cannot import `NotNull` from either the same package as `Nullable` nor the declared Java EE 7 package.

Answer (score 4):

Don't confuse Java SE and Java EE: [Differences between Java SE and Java EE.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/firstcup/doc/gkhoy.html)

There is no Java EE 8 yet, it's in [planning mode](https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/pages/Home). You can use Jave EE 7's [`NotNull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html) just fine. Just get the appropriate libraries.

**<sub>There's obviously no javadoc for a library that doesn't exist, thus the 404 .</sub>**

Note that specifying an `import` statement simply makes it possible to refer to types by their simple name rather than by their fully qualified name. It does nothing to actually provide the classes at runtime or compile time. You still need to find the appropriate libraries, possibly packaged as a `.jar`, and put them on your compile time and runtime classpath, as required.